# To add a JSON Array inside a JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

Am working in MVC. In my controller am creating a list

```
 public class GridColModelLst
    {
        List<GridColModel> _items = new List<GridColModel>();

        public List<GridColModel> items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }
    }


    public class GridColModel
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int? width { get; set; }
    }
```

And passing this list as JSON which works fine and my JSON is below

```
[{ name: 'Humidity', width: 90}]
```

How do i make it like the below JSON To add a JSON Array inside a JSON object in C#

```
[{ name: 'Humidity', width: 90, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } }]
```

Thanks

====================

update

In my controller am sending the list like

```
return Json(Colmodel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and am getting  `[{ name: 'Humidity', width: 90}]`  succesfully

What changes i need for the class to get a JSON like

```
[{ name: 'Humidity', width: 90, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 return Json(new { name = "Humidity", width = 90, searchoptions = new { sopt = new string[] { "eq,nq" } } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Am returning JSONRESULT using MVC Controller

Comment: Can you do return Json(some object)

Comment: Yes i did that n i got the josn object. My questoin is what change i need to make in C# to add Json array inside json object. See my 2nd JSON in my question